# Socket.IO Can't emit message from serer to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a connection with the server and client and have the server listening for a player to be made in the lobby. The server receives the player name and updates the player, however, when emitting the player back to the client I am having issues.

### Simply, the pseudo-structure of our implementation follows as such...

Server

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ ....
         socket.emit('ack', {....

         socket.on('createPlayer', function(data){
                          .... (update newPlayer object)  .....
                           socket.emit('newPlayer', {
                                         playerName: newPlayer.name
                              [...]
```

Client

```
let socket = io();

socket.on('ack', function(data) {
            console.log('ack', data)
} 

socket.on('newPlayer', function(data) {
              console.log('newPlayer', data)
```

---

When a connection is made by the client's browser to the server, the 'ack' message is sent and received and logged to the client's console. But, When the client makes a new player and the 'createPlayer' socket.on is hit it tries to emit the new player back to the client but is never received.

Any suggestions as to why the client would never receive the sent message?

Comment: From where the ```createPlayer``` event emitted?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for sending message to all connected clients:

```
io.emit('event_name', msg);
```

Also you should use this for all clients except new clients:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('event_name', msg);
```

This function is for sending message to new client that sent message at that time:

```
socket.emit('event_name', msg)
```

You can send specified client using this method:

```
io.to(socketId).emit('event_name', data)
```